# How do you use Pytorch model's function in Onnx to get output instead of model.forward() function

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

**TL;DR: How can I use `model.whatever_function(input)` instead of `model.forward(input)` for the `onnxruntime`**?

I use [CLIP embedding](https://github.com/openai/CLIP) to create embedding for my Image and texts as:

[Code is from the official git merge](https://github.com/openai/CLIP/pull/219)

```
! pip install ftfy regex tqdm
! pip install git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP.git

import clip
import torch

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

model, preprocess = clip.load("RN50", device=device) # Load any model
model = model.eval() # Inference Only

img_size = model.visual.input_resolution
dummy_image = torch.randn(10, 3, img_size, img_size).to(device)
image_embedding = model.encode_image(dummy_image).to(device))

dummy_texts = clip.tokenize(["quick brown fox", "lorem ipsum"]).to(device)
model.encode_text(dummy_texts)
```

and it works fine giving me `[Batch, 1024]` tensors for both for the loaded model.

Now I have quantized my model in `Onnx` as:

```
model.forward(dummy_image,dummy_texts) # Original CLIP result (1)

torch.onnx.export(model, (dummy_image, dummy_texts), "model.onnx", export_params=True,
  input_names=["IMAGE", "TEXT"],
  output_names=["LOGITS_PER_IMAGE", "LOGITS_PER_TEXT"],
  opset_version=14,
  dynamic_axes={
      "IMAGE": {
          0: "image_batch_size",
      },
      "TEXT": {
          0: "text_batch_size",
      },
      "LOGITS_PER_IMAGE": {
          0: "image_batch_size",
          1: "text_batch_size",
      },
      "LOGITS_PER_TEXT": {
          0: "text_batch_size",
          1: "image_batch_size",
      },
  }
)
```

and the model is saved.

When I test the model as :

```
# Now run onnxruntime to verify
import onnxruntime as ort

ort_sess = ort.InferenceSession("model.onnx")
result=ort_sess.run(["LOGITS_PER_IMAGE", "LOGITS_PER_TEXT"], 
  {"IMAGE": dummy_image.numpy(), "TEXT": dummy_texts.numpy()})
```

It gives me a list of length 2, one for each image and text and the `result[0]` has shape of `[Batch,2]`.

Comment: `forward` is the function called by PyTorch as part of the `nn.Module`'s routine defined inside of its `__call__` function. If you call `forward` or any other function with the intent of performing inference, you will essentially bypass all of PyTorch processing. It is unclear where you would like to go with this...

Comment: @Ivan I want to call `model.encode_image()` for the `Onnx` model. Is it possible? does not matter what do I have to do. I just want to get embedding from the quantized model instead of binary results which you get from `model(input)` or `model.forward(input)`

Comment: You could override `forward` before exporting it to Onnx?

Comment: but it's a pre-trained model so  wouldn't it affect the overall thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `encode_image` on your module isn't calling `forward` then nothing is stopping you from overriding `forward` before exporting to Onnx:

```
>>> model.forward = model.encode_image
>>> torch.onnx.export(model, (dummy_image, dummy_texts), "model.onnx", ...))
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Worked as expected. Giving 50 ms boost. Will check the results but that wasn't the original question.